# Кавычки при имени

Tags: пунктуация, ономастика, кавычки, имена

Из [статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0) о "Гусарской балладе" на Википедии:

> На удивлённые вопросы французов испанец, помня хорошее обращение Шурочки с ним в плену, заявляет, что она — его младший брат, по семейной традиции тоже носящий *имя «Винсенто»* (курсив мой — А. Л.).

Правильно ли, что имя взято в кавычки?

Comment: Отвечу здесь на Ваш вопрос: потому, что курсива в исходнике нет, и введение выделения в цитируемый текст будет нарушением правил цитирования, если об этом не заявить тут же.

Comment: @shampar: а когда цитируют с Грамоты, например, и, наоборот, **не** делают соответствующих выделений (я обычно выделяю, как у них, но просто так, п. ч. так красиво и наглядно, а другие часто нет), получается, они тоже нарушают правила цитирования и должны делать аналогичные пометки?

Comment: Нарушение есть нарушение.

Comment: Насчет "нарушений" Вообще-то есть две прямо противоположные рекомендации. Либо указывать, что выделение (курсивом, полужирным) - авторское, тогда по умолчанию все неоговоренные особенности внесены цитирующим. Либо наоборот. Искать пруфы лениво, поверьте в данном случае на слово. Я, как и многие другие авторы, склоняюсь именно ко второй версии. Идея оговаривать только особенности первоисточника упирается в то, что список таких особенностей никем не утвержден, следовательно всегда есть вероятность ввести читающего в заблуждения.

Comment: Но, коли такая ситуация с двумя противоположными рекомендациями существует, то смое разумное - оговаривать всё: и особенности цитирования и выделения первоисточника. Тем не менее, говорить об ошибке/нарушении цитирования я бы не стал ни в одном случае. цитирования я  бы не стал.

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях имя в кавычки не заключается, даже если очень хочется или кажется, что это уместно (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309585)). Поэтому правильно будет кавычки не ставить.

*На удивлённые вопросы французов испанец, помня хорошее обращение Шурочки с ним в плену, заявляет, что она — его младший брат, по семейной традиции тоже носящий имя **Винсенто**.*

Но если в целом, то имя, заключённое в кавычки, конечно же, можно увидеть, только вот при других обстоятельствах. Например, при цитировании: "Он сказал: «Иван» — и пошёл дальше". Или когда имя выступает в роли названия чего-либо (роман "Лолита", фильм "Александр", сериал "Вангелия" и т. д.).

Answer (score 0):

Если убрать кавычки, то предложение приобретёт двусмысленность. Можно прочитать в таком смысле: "Носил имя, принадлежавшее некому Винсенто" вместо "имя, которое есть Винсенто".

Если проблему описал непонятно, то на ещё раз, на пальцах:

"Носящий имя Артём"

"Носящий имя Артёма"

В склоняемых именах кавычки не нужны, так как падеж избавляет от двусмысленности. Но "Винсенто" может нуждаться в таком дополнении, оно оправдано.

Comment: Спасибо, понял мысль, но мне кажется, что этот вариант очень маловероятен. Если имеется в виду другое его имя, тогда как раз надо писать по-другому, чтобы избегать этой двусмысленности.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я, к сожалению, не по понял про "друге его имя".

Comment: Ну его зовут Винсенто, какое у него ещё может быть имя? Другое тогда.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой быть может, я так и не понял, но ни в своём ответе, ни в вопросе я мысли о другом имени не вижу. Человека представляют единожды кому-то незнакомому и сообщают, что это человек, носящий имя "Винсенто" (кавычки указывают на то, что это им.п., а не р.п.)

Comment: А если это родительный падеж, что подразумевается? Если имя Винсенто, то у него же нет другого имени! Зачем родительный падеж тогда?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой скажем там, если родительный падеж, то мы подчёркиваем, что это имя уже кому-то принадлежало до него. "Носящий имя Генриха -- одного из величайших людей в его династии". То есть, названный в честь кого-то, у кого уже есть такое имя. Я это подразумеваю

Comment: В моей фразе так понять нельзя!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой ну да, благодаря кавычкам. Иначе почему бы и не понять, что семейная традиция заключается в том, чтобы всех называть в честь какого-то первоначального Альфонсо? Но это я вернулся уже к началу. Вас такое объяснение, я понял, не убедило.

Comment: Надо очень постараться, чтобы так понять. А вообще, очевидно, что имеется в виду само имя. И вовсе не благодаря кавычкам ясно, а из здравого смысла. Если даже допустить, что речь может идти о другом человеке, в тех случаях и надо это делать ясным, перефразируя, когда родительный падеж совпадает с именительным.