# У Вас фамилия «Медведева» — не «Медведьева»(,) — так?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> У Вас фамилия *Медведева* — не *Медведьева*(,) — так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кавычки не нужны. Можете посмотреть [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460621/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) (там, правда, про имена, но это правило действует и на фамилии).

Посмотрим без вставки:

*У Вас фамилия Медведева, так?*

Частица *так (разг.)* в вашем примере употребляется в ожидании утвердительного ответа на вопрос. Она обособляется. Со вставкой тоже будет обособляться:

*У Вас фамилия Медведева — не Медведьева, — так?*

Вставка относится к предыдущей части, поэтому разделяем запятой вторую часть и вставку, чтобы не разрывать связь между вставкой и первой частью.